# Panels: Targeting content to panel-2 from submenu placed in panel-1

Tags: panels, navigation

On my site in Main Menu among other links I have a link called *Photos* that leads to photos.

In Taxonomy I've created vocabulary *Photocategory* to categorize my Photos.

I want to create Page (for photos) that have two regions:
(1) In **first region** I would like to have a list of *Photocategories* linked to each *photocategory* plus some custom links.
(2) **Second region** would be the place where items from chosen photocategories (listed in first region) will be displayed.

For **first region** I am using "My Menu" with dynamically generated *Photocategories* links (by Menu Views Module). This solution gives me ability to add pages like photos-home-page and photos-info-page to "My Menu"

**Second region** would be a "landing region" for links from "My Menu"

I have started by crating Custom Page with panelized regions, one region for "My Menu" and second region for as "landing region". But from this point I don't know how to tell Drupal to:
(a) **relate/connect links from My Menu to "landing region"**
and how to:
(b) **choose position from "My Menu" to be displayed as default/home** for this "panelized Custom Page structure"

[image]